# Integrability and resolution of an exponential integral

Tags: integration

First of all that poblem i am facing is to prove the integrability of that function $f(x,y)=e^{-xy}$ in the domain $[0,\infty]\times[a,b]$ with $0<a<b$.
I know that I need the Fubini and Tonelli Theorems for do that, but I couldn't prove that because I don't know how to use them and do the proof with that. Then I need to solve that integral using, I think, the result of the integrability. This is the integral I couldn't solve:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x}\mathop{dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can use Tonelli theorem for nonnegative functions.
If  one of the iterated integrals is finite, so is the other, and they are equal.

We have
$$\int\limits_a^b\left (\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-xy}\,dx\right )\,dy=\int\limits_a^b{1\over y}\,dy=\ln b-\ln a$$
On the other hand
$$ \int\limits_0^\infty\left (\int\limits_a^b e^{-xy}\,dy\right )\,dx= \int\limits_0^\infty {e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}\over x}\,dx $$